# qt double click pushbutton

Tags: qt, click, qpushbutton

Как сделать сигнал `doubleClicked` для кнопки? Через `QMouseEvent` не получается, хотя там функционал есть.

т.е., хотелось бы через `connect(button , SIGNAL(doubleClicked()) , SLOT(onDoubleClicked()));` связать кнопку с двойным кликом мыши.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос на английском, там есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383722/qwidget-with-doubleclick

Comment: спасибо, но я видел этот пример. К сожалению, не понял - он у меня не заработал.

Comment: Вопрос несколько в ином. у отправителя button  нет сигнала doubleClicked. Как его создать (или переопределить) не понимаю

Comment: в qt нет таких сигналов, но есть вирт. функции, вам надо вывести свой класс из QPushButton и в нём переопределить функцию `void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *)` как в примере приведённом @ГерманБорисов

Comment: Немного в сторонку. Вообще, вешать двойной клик на кнопку - не комильфо, кнопка есть кнопка - UX не очень одобряет, разве что для домашних поделок. Зачем вам двойной клик на кнопку?

Comment: разный функционал на signal click и  double click.

Comment: Pavel Gridin , а вы мне другой пример, отличный от вышеприведенного, можете привести?

Comment: всем огромное  спасибо, разобрался как делать. Тему можно закрывать.